# how to use ionice with alias

Tags: alias, zsh

ionice does not seem to work with aliases. I am using zsh, I did not test bash. e.g.

$ alias foo='ls -l'
$ ionice -c2 -n2 foo
ionice: executing foo failed: No such file or directory

Why does ionice not recognice the alias and how can I get it to recognize the alias?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a global alias:

```
alias -g foo='ls -l'
```